# React: How to update a component from another

Tags: reactjs

I have a CRUD page that includes two components, `<Create />` and `<List />`. Users can **update/delete** in the `<List />` component.

I have no access to the newly created value. Is there a way I can send a signal from the `<Create />` component to the `<List />` component so `<List />` can query the back-end for the new data?

```
<>
  <Create onCreate={handleCreate} />
  <List onDataChange={handleDataChange} />
</>
```

Comment: Can you outline a specific scenario please?

Comment: Lift up the list state and pass it to the list component.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple ways to do this, but the simplest way would be to have the reference to that data be in the parent component for both of these other components like this:

```
function Parent() {

  const [data, setData] = React.useState([])
  
  const handleCreate = (item) => {
    setData(prevData => [...prevData, item])
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Create onCreate={handleCreate} />
      <List data={data} />
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: This sounds like a good approach. But in my case, I have no access to the newly created data. Is there a way to send a signal from create component to list component, so list component can query backend for the new data?

Comment: @jason135 I would need more info regarding how you would know that new data was created if you cannot access that data. In my understanding React is declarative and as such there is no really good way to say 'hey List, update now please'.  Instead you're supposed to pass List the data and expect that it knows what to do with it.